# Session expiration issues with various browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, cookies, session

For a while now, I have been having issues with several websites, which tell me either just after logging in, or after one or two clicks, that my session has expired and I need to log in again.

Problem history: At first I thought it was the website's fault. After it occurred on several unrelated websites, I thought it was Chrome's fault as for at least some of these websites, the problem did not occur when using Firefox. Then later I found a website where also Firefox (or Microsoft Edge) didn't work, and I thought it had to do specifically with that website. But now I have encountered the same issue, for all my browsers, on at least two unrelated websites (namely https://www.sbb.ch and https://www.digid.nl).

Can anyone tell me what is causing these issues? And how do I prevent this, so that I can actually use these websites again?

What I have tried: So far I have tried removing cookies for these websites in different browsers, but the problem remains. I am also positive that my name/password combination is correct on both. If I use a different combination, it specifically tells me the combination is incorrect. As mentioned, I have tried these websites using Chrome, Firefox and Microsoft Edge, all while using Windows 10. I do not have any specific additional firewalls installed as far as I know. I'm usually accessing the internet via a semi-public WiFi network (password-protected) hosted by the apartment complex I'm living in, if that's relevant.

---

*Edit:* To add to the above: the same websites do work properly when accessing them from work (with a different machine, on a different network). So either the problem is related to my machine, or to the network used to access these sites.

Comment: So you could try a A-B test to locate the problem, bring your office machine to home, or your home machine to office, and test the problem websites.

Comment: Do you use any snakeoil internet security software?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you still face this problem, but maybe check your home computer's time settings. If any of those sites does time-based checks to handle session lifecycle management, wrong time settings could cause some trouble.

Answer (score -3):

Umm you could have a virus? It is always common that you install or run something that has a virus in it. Have you downloaded and ran any files recently? Do you have a "decent" anti-virus? (I say decent because there is no "perfect" anti-virus).

Comment: Would a virus cause this behavior? And I'm not an IT pro, but also not a total idiot computer-wise, so I haven't run any weird, untrusted software. (To be sure I'm running another full scan with Windows Defender, but I doubt this is the answer.)

Comment: Just to confirm: this is not it.

Comment: This kind of "you have a virus" is one of those cliche go-to answers given when the person subjected to the question is simply puzzled by it and can't give an answer. If you don't know the answer for sure, please refrain from write anything in this site at all.